# Obtain location of input within table cell HTML

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a a table with inputs inside each table cell like so:

```
<table width="300" border="1" align="center" id="mainTable">
  <tr>
    <td><input onkeyup="insertToArray(value)" size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
    <td><input onkeyup="insertToArray(value)" size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
    <td><input onkeyup="insertToArray(value)" size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
    <td><input onkeyup="insertToArray(value)" size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to know how to obtain the location (row and column) of an input within the table (using javascript). I know how to do it for a regular cell with nothing inside, but for an input within the cell I can't seem to find a way. The function inside the input is for another purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a great way to do it.

I have 2 global variables representing the column and the row objects (tr, td)

```
function returnParent(x)
{
    parentOfInput = x.parentNode; //td level
    parentOfTd = parentOfInput.parentNode; //tr level
}
```

And I call this function alongside the other as well like so (note that I call returnParent() first since I want the position first thing when I enter something in input):

```
<table width="300" border="1" align="center" id="mainTable">
  <tr>
    <td><input onkeyup="returnParent(this); insertToArray(value);" size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
    <td><input onkeyup="returnParent(this); insertToArray(value);" size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
    <td><input onkeyup="returnParent(this); insertToArray(value);" size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
    <td><input onkeyup="returnParent(this); insertToArray(value);" size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
```

Finally in my insertToArray(value) function, I get the column and row like so:

```
function insertToArray(value)
{

    var a = value;
    //get the cell position using parentNode
    tableCol = parentOfInput.cellIndex;
    tableRow = parentOfTd.rowIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the call to the function `insertToArray(value)` to `insertToArray(this)` and then inside the function do

```
function insertToArray(elem){
            ...

            var tdElem = elem.parentNode;
            var trElem = tdElem.parentNode; 
            console.log("Row: " + trElem.rowIndex);
            console.log("Column: " + tdElem.cellIndex);

            ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get a reference to the table cell, then you just have to get access to the children inside of that node.

You can use `childNodes' which returns a NodeList object and then you use the index to access the children so in your case, the input box.

example:

```
document.getElementById("firstTableCell").childNodes[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I adopted the following approach, though it uses the keyup listener from jquery:

HTML:

```
<table width="300" border="1" align="center" id="mainTable">
  <tr>
    <td><input size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
    <td><input size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
    <td><input size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
    <td><input size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
    <td><input size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
    <td><input size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
    <td><input size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$("#mainTable input").keyup(function() {
  var colIndex = $(this).parent()[0].cellIndex;
  var rowIndex = $(this).parent()[0].parentElement.rowIndex;
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If he wants to use jQuery, this is a nice approach, otherwise you will need to tweak it to JS.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in different ways, the code I included here is just to help you understand it better and depending on what you want to do, this is a nice easy approach to your issue. You can get the indexes instead, again, it depends on what you want to do.

HTML:

```
<table width="300" border="1" align="center" id="mainTable">
  <tr class="row1">
    <td><input class="tableCell" id="cell1" size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
    <td><input class="tableCell" id="cell2" size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
    <td><input class="tableCell" id="cell3" size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
    <td><input class="tableCell" id="cell4" size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
window.onload = function() {
  var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("tableCell");
  for (var x = 0; x < cells.length; x++) {
    cells[x].addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {

    //  get row class name: 
    var rowClass = (e.target).parentElement.parentElement.className;
    alert("Row classname: " + rowClass);

    // get the value insede the cell:
    var cellValue = (e.target).value;
    alert("Value entered: " + cellValue);

    var cellId = e.target.id;
    alert("Cell ID: " + cellId);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a utility method that to looks for the closest parent
using a tag name:

Here's an example

```js
function getClosestParent( needle, haystack ) {
 var parent = null;
 var target = needle.toUpperCase();
 var element = haystack.parentElement;

 while ( parent == null ) {
  if ( element !== null ) {
   if ( element.tagName === target ) {
    parent = element;
   }
  }
  else {
   break;
  }

  element = element.parentElement;
 }

 return parent;
}

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var row = getClosestParent("tr", this)
  var column = getClosestParent("td", this)

  alert(row);
  alert(column);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="300" border="1" align="center" id="mainTable">
  <tr>
    <td><input onkeyup="insertToArray(value)" size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```